# How to know whether am the administrator of my Ubuntu?

Tags: user-management

Is there a way to know whether am the administrator of my Ubuntu 14.04 ? If not, how can I became the administrator ?

Comment: Note that though you keep saying "the administrator", all the answers have spoken of whether or not you are "an administrator". There isn't necessarily a sole administrator (unless you perhaps count the root account, which is normally disabled). You can very well have a hundred administrators on a machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the default GUI, open the System Settings and go to the “User Accounts” tool. This shows your “Account Type”: “Standard” or “Administrator”.

On the command line, run the command `id` or `groups` and see whether you are in the `sudo` group. On Ubuntu, normally, administrators are in the `sudo` group.

You may have administrative access if you've been directly added to the list of sudoers — this is more likely if the administrator is familiar with Linux or Unix in general and didn't use the default Ubuntu method. Try running `sudo echo ok` and enter your password; if this prints `ok`, you're an administrator.

Comment: The first one you said is the easiest way. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Simply type `id` in a terminal. It outputs user id, group id, and group memberships of your account. In my case:

```
UID=1000(jacob) GID=1000(jacob) groepen=1000(jacob),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30
```

"27(sudo)" means I am member of the group "sudo", and that I have the option to run commands with `sudo`, in other words: I am an administrator.

In comparison, a "normal" user's output:

```
UID=1001(testpersoon) GID=1001(testpersoon) groepen=1001(testpersoon),1000(jacob)
```

To turn a "normal" user into an administrator, add the user to the group `sudo`:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo  (from an administrator's user account)
```

Comment: I also got 4(adm). So am I the administrator ?

Comment: @tom means he want to know if he is a root or not

Comment: @nux Why do you think so?

Comment: from the title , " The administrator of my ubuntu "

Comment: @nux but administrator != root isn't it?

Comment: @nux Being an administrator means having the right to run programs as root. It doesn't mean using the root account all the time.

Comment: all users other than root are standard users , standard users are both users can have some root privileges and some not

Comment: @nux ...standard user *with* administrator priveleges = administrator, *not* root.

Comment: yes that's what am talking , i know they are totally different

Comment: but what am talking OP means he want to know if he is root or not , this title come from a windows user :)

Answer (score 2):

By default root account is disabled in ubuntu , root account has UID = 0 , try :

`id` and see what is the output , if its other than zero you are not the root .

But you can check if you can use root privileges by sudo :

```
sudo -v
```

If you cant it will state :

```
Sorry, user [username] may not run sudo on [hostname].
```

Another tips when you open terminal :

```
If $ at the end of the prompt that means standard user .

If # that means root user
```

In my case `nux@ubuntu-PC:~$`

That means i am a standard user .

Comment: What you mean by this - "id - u (yourusername) " ? will you explain it a little ?

Comment: check http://www.linfo.org/uid.html

Comment: Mine is $. So am I the administrator ?

Comment: @Tom Even if you are an administrator, your prompt will normally show `$`. The prompt only shows `#` if the shell is running as root. If you merely *have the right to run programs as root* (which is the definition of being an administrator), that doesn't affect your prompt.

Comment: administrator is a standard user , isn't it ?

Comment: here $ and # state am a root or not using the bash