# How can I find whether I am a sudo user or not

Tags: password, sudo, user-management

I am asked for sudo password frequently while entering sudo commands in the terminal, but I can't remember whether I am a sudo user or not. Similarly I don't know any superuser do password. I am confused in this password matter.

EXAMPLE:

```
$ sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for deepak:
```

I don't know what to do in the previous password asking command. Similarly like above example, for many times I am asked for sudo password. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### It's just your regular password.

The password to run commands with `sudo` is *your* password, not a separate password. It is the same password that:

- you came up with and typed in when you installed Ubuntu or created your account
- you type in on the login screen (unless you have automatic login)
- you type in to unlock the screen

When you're asked for your password in a terminal, [it is normal that nothing is shown while you are typing it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password). To enter your password for the `sudo` command, type it in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

- If you enter your password correctly and you *are* an administrator--which on Ubuntu means a user who is allowed to perform actions as the root user through [`sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) and [polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit)--then the command will run. (Non-administrators can be permitted to run certain commands with `sudo` too, but this is not set up by default.)
- If you enter your password correctly but you are not an administrator and aren't allowed to run the command as root with `sudo`, you'll get an error:

  ```
  username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
  ```

  ("Reported" just means written to a log file. Attempting to run a command with `sudo` on your own computer that your user account isn't set up to be allowed to run is harmless, and the scary "This incident will be reported" thing can be ignored.)

#### To see if you're set up to `sudo` to root, check if you're in the `sudo` group.

Another way to find out if your user account is an administrator and allowed to run commands as root with `sudo` is to check if it's a member of the `sudo` group. To list all the groups you're in, run:

```
groups
```

Users are usually in their own group (named the same as their username) and several other groups. If you're an administrator the output of `groups` will look something like:

```
username adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

If you're not an administrator it will look something like this (i.e., it will not contain `sudo`):

```
username adm cdrom dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

If you only have one user account and it's been removed from the `sudo` group, see [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user) This is not a very common situation, though.

#### For more detailed information, you can ask `sudo` about your abilities.

A third way to find out if you're an administrator is to run `sudo -l`. You'll have to enter your password. Then:

- Non-administrators who aren't set up to run any commands with `sudo` will see the message

  ```
  Sorry, user username may not run sudo on host.
  ```

  where *`username`* is your username and *`host`* is the hostname (computer name) of your Ubuntu system.
- Administrators (i.e., members of the `sudo` group) will see some information ending in the lines:

  ```
  User username may run the following commands on host:
  (ALL : ALL) ALL
  ```
- Users who are set up to run some commands as root but not all commands will see output documenting their abilities. (See [`man 5 sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) for technical details.)

#### *Further Reading*

- [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) (in the Ubuntu help wiki -- I highly recommend reading this, to understand `sudo` in Ubuntu)
- The manpage for `sudo`, which you can read by running the command `man sudo`, or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/sudo.8.html).
- [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) and [Superuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) on Wikipedia
- Ask Ubuntu's [tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/sudo/info) for [sudo](/questions/tagged/sudo)
- [How to NOT become a root user? Are administrators root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245201/how-to-not-become-a-root-user-are-administrators-root)
- [How to know whether am the administrator of my Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473981/how-to-know-whether-am-the-administrator-of-my-ubuntu)
- [How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)

Comment: i really gained somethings from your guidance and i think probably you are helping me by answering my questions.i think you may be the helper for all my queries in this field ELIAH KAGAN

Answer (score 2):

```
getent group sudo | grep your-user-name
```

If you find your username among the list from command above then you are a sudo.

To use a sudo with no password **which is not advised at all and make you in risk to hurt your system**

Open terminal window and type:

```
sudo visudo
```

In the bottom of the file, type the follow:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```